# Display all existing members

Tags: loop, users, user-meta, profiles

How would I (using a loop) pull in all of the existing users? I'm trying to loop through these users and then pull in meta data for each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `get_users()`.

```
$args = array(
    'fields' => 'all_with_meta',
);
$users = get_users( $args );
foreach( $users as $user ) {
    // your display code here
    var_dump( $user );  // so you can see what's in $user
}
```

`all_with_meta` will get the user and all the associated meta, if I'm reading the Codex page right.

**Update:** After testing the code, I find that `'number' => -1` returns nothing at all, so I removed it from the code.

#### Reference

- [`get_users()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users)

Comment: Thank you!, This worked perfectly; I wasn't aware this function existed, so thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Generally, in my experience with WordPress, if I'm trying to figure out if there's a function that does X, there is.  Bookmark the Codex's Function Reference, if you haven't already:  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/ -- that's the best place to start.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "pull in", but if you are looking to display a list of users on your website, then my http://www.wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-user-listing plugin might help. /end gratuitous self-promotion